# php login form using mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I created an account on 000webhost to create html page that has a login form. But I am facing errors when i try to connect the form to the database.

Here is the html code:

```
  <html>

   <head>
      <title>Login Page</title>

      <style type = "text/css">
         body {
            font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size:14px;
         }

         label {
            font-weight:bold;
            width:100px;
            font-size:14px;
         }

         .box {
            border:#666666 solid 1px;
         }
      </style>

   </head>

   <body bgcolor = "#FFFFFF">




      <div align = "center">
         <div style = "width:300px; border: solid 1px #333333; " align = "left">
            <div style = "background-color:#333333; color:#FFFFFF; padding:3px;"><b>Login</b></div>

            <div style = "margin:30px">

               <form method="POST" action="C1.php">
                  <label>UserName  :</label><input type = "text" name = "username" required = "box"/><br /><br />
                  <label>Password  :</label><input type = "password" name = "password" required = "box" /><br/><br />


                  <input type = "submit" name="submit" value = " Login "/><br />

               </form>

               <div style = "font-size:11px; color:#cc0000; margin-top:10px"><?php echo $error; ?></div>

            </div>

         </div>

      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

here is my php page

```
       <?php
 session_start();
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "******";
$password = "******";

// Create connection
$database_name = "id2425621_login";
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database_name);

 if (isset($_POST['submit']))
        {     

    $username='king';
    $password='king123';

    $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM mylogin WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'");
     if (mysqli_num_rows($query) != 0)
    {
     echo "sucess";   
      }
      else
      {
    echo "fail";
    }
    }
    ?>
```

mysql has a table named mylogin and has the values:

```
INSERT INTO `mylogin`(`username`, `password`) VALUES ('king','king123')
```

I couldn't connect to the database, appreciate your help in advance

Thanks

Comment: `if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}`

Use this and check what you get an error.

Comment: shows blank page

Comment: @turki See the error log or at top of your page after session_start(); write error_reporting(E_ALL); to see the error

Comment: If you show your error then it would be more helpful to give solution. Can you try by this line  if (mysqli_num_rows($query) >0) instead of  if (mysqli_num_rows($query) != 0)

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Use prepared statements with value placeholders instead.

Comment: You should also store only password hashes in the database. Not the password itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are open to sql injection. So use prepared query.

Replace your php code:

```
<?php
session_start();
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "******";
$password = "******";

// Create connection
$database_name = "id2425621_login";
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database_name);
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }
    $username=$_POST['username']; // username value get by form using $_POST
    $password=$_POST['password']; // password value get by form using $_POST
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "SELECT * FROM mylogin WHERE username=? AND password=?");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ss', $username, $password);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    if (mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt) > 0){
        echo "sucess";   
    } else {
        echo "fail";
    }
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    mysqli_close($conn);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Do checking for connection. Check error log if got any clues.

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database_name);
// Check connection
if (!$conn)
{
  die("Connection error: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

Hope this help you. [For reference](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_connect_error.asp)

Comment: I get the message "success" no matter what enter in username and password

Comment: I think your problem is here, `$username='king'; $password='king123';`
try use another variable because it might confuse with `$username` and `$password` from the database.

Comment: what do u suggest, I am really stuck

Answer (score -1):

Here is your Answer

```
<?php
session_start();
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "******";
$password = "******";

// Create connection
$database_name = "id2425621_login";
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database_name);
if (!$conn) {
    die(mysqli_error($conn));
}
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{     
    $username='abc';
    $password='abc123';

    $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM mylogin WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'");
    if(!$query){
        echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($conn));
    } else if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){
        echo "success";  
    } else {
       echo "invalid user name or password";
    }
}
?>
```